# using ng-click to change factory value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a factory in which I'm setting a language property to a string. Now I want to change this property when a user clicks an image on my website (the idea here is to change the whole pages website when the flag is clicked). So far the pages language changes (using `ng-show` for this) when I change it by hand, but I can't get it to change when pressing the image.

my factory:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('langService', [])
    .factory('Language', function() {
        var myFactory = {};

        myFactory.language = 'slo';

        return myFactory;
    });
```

my controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ZICApp')
    .controller('navbarController', function ($scope, Language) {
        $scope.language = Language.language;
    });
```

my html:

```
  <div id="navbar" ng-controller="navbarController">
    <ul>
      <li><a ng-click="language = 'eng'"><img src="images/EN.gif"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The content which needs to change is inside a view file, as well as in the template. If you need additional information about the project please let me know, tried to trim it down as much as I can.

Comment: it's kinda too big for plunkr, see the git repo here https://github.com/Shooshte/ZIC-dist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your factory needs a method like

```
        myFactory.setLanguage = function(lang) {
            myFactory.language = lang;
        };
```

While your controller should implement a method like

```
        $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang) {
            Language.setLanguage(lang);
        }
```

And your ng-click calls `changeLanguage('eng')`

---

***Resulting factory:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('langService', [])
    .factory('Language', function() {
        var myFactory = {};

        myFactory.language = 'slo';
        myFactory.setLanguage = function(lang) {
            myFactory.language = lang;
        };

        return myFactory;
});
```

***Resulting controller:***

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ZICApp')
    .controller('navbarController', function ($scope, Language) {
        $scope.language = Language.language;
        $scope.changeLanguage = function(lang) {
            Language.setLanguage(lang);
        }
    });
```

***Resulting HTML:***

```
<div id="navbar" ng-controller="navbarController">
    <ul>
        <li><a ng-click="changeLanguage('eng')"><img src="images/EN.gif"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

**EDIT**
[skubski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804081/using-ng-click-to-change-factory-value/33804231?noredirect=1#comment55374457_33804231) is absolutely right, the variable should be hold privately. To achieve this, you could change the factory like this:

```
angular.module('langService', [])
    .factory('Language', function() {
        var language = 'slo';

        function setLanguage(lang) {
            //...optional logic
            language = lang;
        }

        function getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }

        return {
            setLanguage: setLanguage,
            getLanguage: getLanguage
        };
});
```

and in the controller change `$scope.language = Language.language;` to `$scope.language = Language.getLanguage();`

Comment: No need to encapsulate the factory method, a reference will suffice. Your  factory also exposes the language variable rendering the setter method useless.

Comment: Since you can handle errors in the getter (i.e. 'language not found') and do some other logic (like clearing the cache in order to update the views once the user changes the language) the setter seems pretty useful to me.

Comment: You do **not have** a getter. You **expose** your variable as **public**, thus making it possible to manipulate without the setter, rendering it a bit useless. Furthermore you would need to rewrite your error handling when using that set method somewhere else.

Comment: You're right, the variable should be hold privately.

Comment: hey, I tried doing this, but for some reason `ng-click="setLanguage('eng')"` does nothing. It works when I change the property in the factory by hand, but not with the ng-click. Do I need to call getLanguage after again after clicking?

Comment: Since the controller doesn't get informed once the language is being changed, yes. Another approach would be to use events (`$rootScope.$broadcast` for example)

Comment: so I can just add something like `$rootScope.$broadcast(language, language);` to the setLanguage function and the whole app gets updated when the language changes?

Comment: `$rootScope.$broadcast` just sends a broadcast, but if there's no one listening it will be useless. The way how you change the language of your app highly depends on the translation-service you are using. In my app's I'm calling `$translate.use(langKey);` and `tmhDynamicLocale.set(langKey);`, for example. See [Angular Dynamic Locale](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale) and [Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate).

Comment: I'm translating everything by hand and then displaying it with ng-show :). Thanks for all the help, got off topic, so I'll dig trough the documentation and try to figure it out

Answer (score 1):

You should use the "." **dot notation** in order to use references to objects and their properties instead of primitive types if you want to access them directly.

You should try changing your factory like this:

```
var myFactory = {};
var myFactory.settings = {
    currentLanguage : 'slo'
};
return myFactory;
```

in the controller:

```
$scope.languageProvider = Language;
```

in the markup access the object's property by reference:

```
<li><a ng-click="languageProvider.settings.currentLanguage = 'eng'"><img src="images/EN.gif"></a></li>
```

Use this method if you need to access the service objects directly, but it is recommended to provide getter/setter methods to access the service data.

**EDIT**
I would go for the setter/getter aproach like iWork suggested.